# Bootstrap Links and Buttons component table lines and title background color change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I use Bootstrap [this Links and buttons](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/list-group/)

I want changed the color for  title background and  table grid lines around link buttons:

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="list-group">
          <h2><a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
          <strong>T I T L E</strong></a>
           <a href="page1.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"> Link 1 </a>              
            <a href="page2.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"> Link 2 </a>   
            <a href="page3.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"> Link 3 </a>          
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"> Link 4 </a>               
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

So how to do it  in my custom css, as it is done for background here:

```
.list-group-item{
    background-color : red;
}
```

To make lines blue [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Loc.png)

Comment: can you tell what do you want?/

Comment: @Ashish sah  Hello, it is described above and show in image, I want change color for table grid lines around link buttons, make it blue for example, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Loc.png

Comment: ok give me  a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey just add this in your CSS and It can help you to modify a lot:

```
.list-group a:first-child  {
 background:red !important;
 border:2px solid yellow;
 }
 .list-group a{
 border:2px solid yellow;
 }
```

Comment: I hope this will help you can target the first element by ```first-child``` selector and give your colour for your grid you can add border  look here I hope this will help you : https://jsbin.com/vukavohace/edit?html,css,output

Comment: exactly, useful

Comment: Bootstrap inbuilt method is causing some kind of problem on hover which is solved here : https://jsbin.com/vukavohace/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-group-item strong{
    background-color : #555;
    border: 1px double #ededed;
}
```

Comment: Hello, this changes background color, and I'm asking for table grid lines around link buttons, added above and here same https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Loc.png

Comment: @user8456381 check.

Comment: @user8456381 I didn't get your question properly. If that works then great :)